# Is it safe to build a floatable speaker?

Tags: safety, 12v, water, underwater

I'm thinking of building a floatable speaker to float along beside me in a lake or a small river while tubing.  I've got some speakers and the following 12V amp:

[DROK Amplify Module Audio Component Amplifier,TDA7297 (TDA7297 15W+15W)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C4MT274)

and I was thinking of using a power bank capable of 12v output to power it, such as this:

[XTPower MP-10000 External Battery Pack with 10000mAh using dual USB 5V and DC 9V / 12V 2A output](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00935L44E)

I was thinking of putting this all in a waterproof pelican box, drilling holes for the speakers, and putting a thin plastic membrane over the speaker cone to prevent water getting in, and throwing in a silica gel packet to absorb moisture.  The speaker cones would also be covered by a metal mesh to protect the plastic membrane, and they would be silicone-sealed to the waterproof box.  I'd have this floating along with me in a small river or a lake.  Theoretically, no water will get in.  So my questions are:

1. If water does get in, is it going to harm anyone in the water?  I can accept damage to the hardware, but I want it to be safe.
2. I know lithium batteries don't mix well with water,  and I think that's what is inside of power banks.  I've seen waterproof power banks, but the only ones I can find can only put out 5V.  Is there a better and safer power source?
3. Is this totally unsafe?

Comment: I'd use a transducer to turn the whole case into a speaker. Might need tighter waterproofing though then.

Comment: 12 volts is not a shock hazard, but you do NOT want the electronics getting wet or even damp. Even if turned off, you may need mild electric heating to keep salty moisture out. A desicate pack has its limits. Consider using speakers with polypropylene cones, which are water proof, and use a sealed enclosure. This is not an answer to all of your questions.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to build anything, there are lots of floating waterproof sound systems available for a reasonable price (under $40) [such as this one from Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00TIYPL7G):

[image]

which has a rechargeable battery and Bluetooth.  You can find others by searching for waterproof pool speakers.  Put your Smartphone [inside a $8 waterproof case](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LBK7OSY) and you're good to go.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Totally unsafe? No, only if badly designed or built. Plenty of commercial products doing the same. RC boats too. The only real concern is waterproofing. Make sure you use sufficient ballast material (foam) and properly seal any Ports. Consider making it completely sealed, with wireless charging and bluetooth audio so that you don't even have ports or Jacks.